# Mocking Relationships in TypeOrm + NestJS

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I'm having difficulty testing a NestJS service which utilises a simple entity that only has one relationship. The related entity, however, is related to many other entities which in turn are also related to other entities. I don't want to import all of the entities and pass to `TypeOrmModule.forRoot`, and if I don't I get an error like the following:

`Entity metadata for Wallet#customer was not found.`

For every entity that has not been imported. Is it possible to "mock" the relationship in some way?

Test:

```js
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(CONNECTION_OPTIONS),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([WalletEntity, WalletTransactionEntity]),
      ],
      providers: [WalletService],
    }).compile();
```

Entity

```js
@Entity('wallet')
export class WalletEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  customerId: string;

  @OneToOne(() => CustomerEntity, (customer) => customer.wallet)
  customer: CustomerEntity;

  @OneToMany(() => WalletTransactionEntity, (transaction) => transaction.wallet)
  transactions: WalletTransactionEntity[];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unit tests, I would suggest not connecting to a live database or using any `imports`, but instead just using custom providers to mock the dependencies of the service you're testing. [This repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) has a bunch of examples including some for TypeORM. A very basic setup, based on the imports you have, might be something like

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  const modRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
      WalletService,
      {
        provide: getRepositoryToken(WalletEntity),
        useValue: walletRepoMock,
      },
      {
        provide: getRepositoryToken(WalletTransactionEntity),
        useValue: walletTransactionRepoMock,
      }
    ]
  }).compile();
});
```

Now you can replace `walletRepoMock` and `walletTransactionRepoMock` with mock implementation of the methods you use for `Repository` and you'll be good to go

Comment: I ended up going this route, thanks for your help Jay!